# Speed up UPDATE from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have the following code:

```
UPDATE tableOne
SET columnOne = CASE
                 WHEN tableOne.columnTwo LIKE '%-02-%' OR tableOne.columnTwo LIKE '%-03-%' OR
                      tableOne.columnTwo LIKE '%-04-%' OR
                      tableOne.columnTwo LIKE '%-05-%' OR
                      tableOne.columnTwo LIKE '%-06-%' OR
                      tableOne.columnTwo LIKE '%-07-%' OR tableOne.columnTwo LIKE '%-08-%' OR
                      tableOne.columnTwo LIKE '%-09-%'
                         THEN tableTwo.columnOne :: text
                 ELSE tableOne.columnOne
    END

FROM tableTwo
WHERE tableTwo.tableId = tableOne.tableId
```

I have two tables. `tableOne` consists of 100 millions of rows (and 40 columns) and `tableTwo` consists of 90 millions of rows. Above query is already in progress for more than 2 days. I am not sure it will ever finish. Is there a way to optimize the query?

If helpful `LIKE` does the following:
Checks if the string (e.g. `2018-06-30 08:20:17`) has listed month. If yes, pick value from `tableTwo` (and CAST it to type `text`), else keep self value (already type `text`).

Comment: Why aren't you storing date/times as date/time (numeric) fields? This is the main improvement you could make.

Comment: Try: `SUBSTRING(tableOne.columnTwo FROM 6 FOR 2) BETWEEN '02' AND '09'`...

Comment: @AndyG will performance be significantly greater if it would have been of type `date` in the first place?

Comment: I would have thought so, searching `Like '%anything%` should be avoided as much as possible, especially 8 times over. Try with a join as well, instead of the WHERE clause, although the database may optimise the difference.

Comment: 100M rows with timestamps in text fields "... because we could not import the data at the very beginning ..." Sigh

Comment: @AndyG: Whether it's `LIKE 'anything%'` or `LIKE '%anything%'` does not make a big difference here as the real heavy lifting is done in the join between the two tables - that will be a seq scan on both tables anyway. The LIKE inside the CASE expression won't add much overhead to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `case` condition to the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE tableOne
    SET columnOne = tableTwo.columnOne::text
FROM tableTwo
WHERE tableTwo.tableId = tableOne.tableId AND
      tableOne.columnTwo ~ '-0[2-9]-' and
      tableOne.columnOne is distinct from tableTwo.columnOne::text;
```

Regular expressions are not really that much faster than a bunch of likes.  The win here is in not updating rows that don't need to be updated.  If the format of `tableOne.columnTwo` is a known format, you could use substring operations instead.

Comment: Or `'-0[2-9]-'` for the regex, probably a bit faster.

Comment: And add `AND columnOne <> tableTwo.columnOne::text` to the WHERE clause to suppress idempotent updates.

Answer (score 1):

What about only updating if month is between 02 and 09

```
UPDATE tableOne
SET columnOne = tableTwo.columnOne :: text
FROM tableTwo
WHERE tableTwo.tableId = tableOne.tableId 
  AND SUBSTRING(tableOne.columnTwo FROM 6 FOR 2) BETWEEN '02' AND '09'
```